# Duplicate Conditional formatting with POI libraries

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, conditional-formatting

I am facing some issues when applying some conditional formatting to an Excel document using POI java library. I am trying to highlight duplicate text values.The below code works properly except for fact that the rule format is not set. When I open the excel document, I see that the rule has been added ([Screen shot of new rule](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3mkDr.png)) but that no format/color has been assigned to it.

```
public void conditionalFormatting() throws Exception {
/* Read Workbook and Identify Color Scale Range */ 

    sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
    List<String> my_range = new ArrayList<>();
    my_range.add("F2:F" + (rowIndex + 1));

/* Add Conditional Formatting Rule */
    CTConditionalFormatting colorScale = sheet.getCTWorksheet().addNewConditionalFormatting();
    colorScale.setSqref(my_range); // Attach Range to conditional formatting set
    CTCfRule myCFRule = colorScale.addNewCfRule(); //create a rule
    myCFRule.setType(STCfType.DUPLICATE_VALUES); // set type of rule to Colour Scale
    myCFRule.setPriority(1); // rule priority = 1
}
```

Does anyone know how to add a format/color to the rule?

Regards, T. Lecoffre

Comment: Why are you messing around with the low-level CT classes? Why not take the easy route and [use the high level POI usermodel classes](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#ConditionalFormatting) adding the conditional formatting?

Answer (score 1):

First up - don't work with the low-level CT classes unless you know what you're doing. Ideally, don't do it even then - too much you can get wrong / miss out!

Instead, you should be using the Apache POI usermodel classes for conditional formatting. There's [documentation on the POI website about them](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#ConditionalFormatting), you can [start here in the JavaDocs to read about it](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/SheetConditionalFormatting.html), or [look at this program in the POI examples](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/examples/src/org/apache/poi/ss/examples/ConditionalFormats.java) for the full set of options available

From the [formatDuplicates method in the Conditional Formats examples](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/examples/src/org/apache/poi/ss/examples/ConditionalFormats.java), you can see that the code you need is something like:

```
 SheetConditionalFormatting sheetCF = sheet.getSheetConditionalFormatting();

 ConditionalFormattingRule rule1 = sheetCF.createConditionalFormattingRule("COUNTIF($F$2:$F$11,F2)>1");
 FontFormatting font = rule1.createFontFormatting();
 font.setFontStyle(false, true);
 font.setFontColorIndex(IndexedColors.BLUE.index);

 CellRangeAddress[] regions = {
            CellRangeAddress.valueOf("F2:F11")
 };

 sheetCF.addConditionalFormatting(regions, rule1);
```

That will highlight the duplicates in Blue

If you want to use colour scales or similar (not sure quite how that would work for duplicates?), then there's an example in the same file too

Answer (score 0):

After studying the "xlsx" file structure I was able to find what I was looking for in order to use the CT classes. In order to understand the POI library I would strongly suggest to anyone to look inside the "xlsx" zip and study the xml files (more specifically - xl/worksheets/{sheet_name}.xml ). Here is the code that I came up with:

```
public void conditionalFormatting() throws Exception {
    /* Read Workbook and Identify Color Scale Range */ 

    sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
    List<String> my_range = new ArrayList<>();
    my_range.add("F2:F" + (rowIndex + 1));

    /* Add Conditional Formatting Rule */
    CTConditionalFormatting colorScale = sheet.getCTWorksheet().addNewConditionalFormatting();
    colorScale.setSqref(my_range); // Attach Range to conditional formatting set
    CTCfRule myCFRule = colorScale.addNewCfRule(); //create a rule
    myCFRule.setType(STCfType.DUPLICATE_VALUES); // set type of rule to Colour Scale
    myCFRule.setPriority(1); // rule priority = 1

    /* Add a differential formatting record */
    myCFRule.setDxfId(createDXFs(wb, 12))
}

/* Create a new differential formatting record */
private static int createDXFs(XSSFWorkbook wb, int size) {
    CTDxfs dxfs = wb.getStylesSource().getCTStylesheet().getDxfs();

    if(dxfs == null) {
        dxfs=wb.getStylesSource().getCTStylesheet().addNewDxfs();
    }

    dxfs.setCount(dxfs.getCount() + 1); // update the dxfs count variable
    CTDxf dxf=dxfs.addNewDxf();

    /* Set rule font size */
    CTFontSize fontSize=dxf.addNewFont().addNewSz();
    fontSize.setVal(size);

    /* Set rule pattern/background color */
    CTFill fill = dxf.addNewFill();
    CTPatternFill pattern = fill.addNewPatternFill();
    CTColor color = pattern.addNewBgColor();
    color.setRgb(javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary("FFF8696B"));

    return (int) dxfs.getCount() - 1; // return the dxf index
}
```

Regards, T. Lecoffre